# Can I make a Complete Red Skeleton

Tags: piece-information

So, it looks like, from searching on Bricklink, there are no red skeleton torsos - only arms and legs. Is that right?

Comment: Neither <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60115> thick nor <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6260> thin torsos are listed in red, correct.

Comment: But people seem to be 3-D printing them: <https://www.flickr.com/photos/148691465@N05/48832081887>

Comment: And (ugh) <http://reasonablyblogged.blogspot.com/2009/04/daily-fail-skeleton-town-treasure.html> knockoffs

Comment: @RSchulz that one isn't printed. It is a legit LEGO piece, but a prototype (you can even see "LEGO" and pert number on thatpicture). TLG use red color (forgot the reason why) to produce most of the prototypes. You can find that there are number of elements, non produced in Red colors being sold over Bricklink.

Comment: Oops, I didn't zoom in - I do see the Lego logo now! I've brought back reddish pieces from Legoland when they used to have a small-volume molding machine on the factory tour. They just remixed various old bricks in and the color was always nonstandard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you can get your hands on a [test-printed torso](https://www.flickr.com/photos/148691465@N05/48832081887).

[image: red skeleton torso]